# Debugging and resolving early session timeout

Tags: php, session

About a year ago, my PHP sessions started timing out - logging clients out of the website. After some reading, I found the suggestion to increase session timeouts which I did in php.ini

```
session.cookie_lifetime=14400
session.gc_maxlifetime=14400
```

Yet, my session continues to timeout after about 60 minutes.

I tried a second option from php.net: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

```
session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 14400]);
```

And still cant get the session to last longer than an hour...

I'm running out of places to check?

PHP Version: 5.6

Comment: did you restart your php process after you made the change to `php.ini` ?

Comment: The array parameter inside `session_start()` only available from PHP 7.0

Comment: @catcon while that is true, setting the `php.ini` should still work

Comment: @Justice: I didn't say it doesn't

Comment: Haven't restarted php but changes were made months ago so php should've been restarted within that time but I will restart just as an extra check.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer - after days, weeks, months of testing and trialling these settings, nothing ever seemed to work ... until I came across this comment on this thread: [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

> Please note that at least two settings are crucial to setting the
>   session time, and maybe three. The two certainly crucial ones are
>   session.gc_maxlifetime and session.cookie_lifetime (where 0 is not the
>   same as some long number). For complete, 100% certainty of allowing
>   long times, it may also be necessary to set the session.save_path, due
>   to varying OS-controled cleanup time on the /tmp directory where
>   session files get stored by default. – @Kzqai Apr 7 '11 at 8:04

I manually set a `session.save_path` and oila! My sessions are now lasting 2+ hours at last check